# How do you do a "where in" sql query with an array data type?

Tags: postgresql

I have a field:

```
dtype ==> character varying(3)[]
```

... but it's an array. So I have for example:

```
ID | name | dtype
1  | one  | {'D10', 'D20', 'D30'}
2  | sam  | {'D20'}
3  | jax  | {'D10', 'D20'}
4  | pam  | {'D10', 'D30'}
5  | pot  | {'D10'}
```

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
select * from table where dtype in ('D20', 'D30')
```

This syntax doesnt work, but the goal is to then return fields 1,2,3,4 but not 5.

Is this possible?

Comment: I would say by using 'overlap' operator `&&`... http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-array.html

Comment: Your table definition and the contents don't match. `character varying(3)` is *not* an array. It's a varchar column with a max. length of 3. But if that were true, you wouldn't be able to store something like `{'D10', 'D20', 'D30'}`. So I guess your column is actually `character varying[]`? Can you do a `\d table_name` and show us the complete table definition?

Comment: if `dtype` is just a normal varchar, postgresql won't know you have placed some data in it that looks like some form of array. Can you use  real [postgresql arrays](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/arrays.html) ?

Comment: So far "unnest" seems to be the best way to go about it, but I was hoping there'd be a better solution.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, it is an array of character varying fields. So it can be {'a', 'ab'} or {'abc', 'def') etc///

Comment: you can use the contains operator as Pavel has suggested: `dtype && array['D20', 'D30']::varchar[]`

Comment: A `text array` value cannot be *in* a set of `text` (= `character varying`) values. Are you want to use an array containment operator (`@>` and `<@`), or the array overlap one `&&`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `&&` operator [as shown in the PostgreSQL manual under "array operators"](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-array.html).

```
select * from table where dtype && ARRAY['D20', 'D30']
```